# События jquery в мобильных устройствах

Tags: jquery, события

```
$('div').on('mouseenter', '.fill', function () {

    //код
});


$('div').on('click', '.fill', function () {

    //код
});
```

Выше мы видим, что при наведении мышки на дивы с классом fill выполняется некоторый код. Также мы видим и событие клик на этих элементах. Всё прекрасно работает и всё меня устраивает при работе с десктопа.

Но при использовании телефона возникает проблема. Хотелось бы, чтобы по клику на эти элементы сразу срабатывал код из второго события. То есть, сейчас с мобильных устройств приходится кликать по элементам 2 раза. При первом клике срабатывает событие наведения, а при втором срабатывает событие клика. Хотелось бы, чтобы при клике с телефона срабатывало сразу событие клик.

Comment: никто не знает?(

Answer (score 0):

Отключите первый скрипт на мобиле, например при ширине экрана меньше 480рх

Comment: ну, там может быть и планшет. пробовал применить event.stopPropagation(), но не работает с разными событиями(

Comment: и даже если отключить функцию на сенсорных экранах, мало ли кто мышь подключит к девайсу